# Would you please help me with adjectives?

Tags: adjectives

Could anybody possibly kindly explain me what is the difference between these?- in meaning.

They are all 10 years old

They are all ten-year-olds

Comment: Actually you have the answer. You have already posted this question in here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/difference-between-ten-years-old-and-ten-year-olds

Comment: @DamkerngT. I don't think it's an exact duplicate of that question (but OP might want to rewrite the question to clarify). *They are all 10 years old* is correct, but *He is a 10 years old boy* is not.